# Set default language with localization

Tags: ios, swift, localization

Is it possible to use a default language for the localization? for example if a key is not found for one language, than the system will look at it automatically in the English language? If it's not possible to do it automatically, would it be possible to do it manually? look for a key in the current language, if not found then force the system to look at it in the English language? In my current app, when a key is not set, the key name is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that do what you want (I didn't find an "official" way to do it).

```
func localizedString(_ key: String) -> String? {
    let localeString = NSLocalizedString(key, comment: "")

    // Base can be changed by en or the default language of your choice
    if localeString == key,
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Base", ofType: ".lproj"),
        let baseBundle = Bundle(path: path) {
        return baseBundle.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: nil)
    }
    return nil
}
```